# Is there a way to make a write-in option available with a Wicket DropDownChoice?

Tags: wicket

I have a list of values in a List of String.
`List<String> listString = Arrays.asList(...)`
But, I'd also like be able to have someone write in a value instead of something from the list.
This is how I populate the list:

```
private final List<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
...
List<String> listString = Arrays.asList(...);
...
theList.addAll(listString);
...
DropDownChoice<String> selections = new DropDownChoice<>("label", theList);
...
```

Is there a different Wicket API that will do this if DropDownChoice will not?

Answer (score 1):

Wicket's DropDownChoice works with HTML `<select>` element. HTMLSelectElement has no `<input>` field for adding custom values.

You need to use more advanced select control, like [Select2](https://select2.org/) or [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/), or any other similar JavaScript widget.

If you decide to use Select2 then check [WicketStuff Select2](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.wicketstuff/wicketstuff-select2/9.1.0/jar)